# How to cache firebaselist/object observables , similar to firebase.js?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, browser-cache, angularfire2

I am trying to understand is there a way for offline responsive APP for selective components to be cached on client side with angular fire 2 observables. Please help.

EDIT 1 :

On below URL I have 2 things I would like to present.

One with chart + number, and in the bottom , I have today's tasks.

Chart number as 11 is updated using callback function of firebase and it retain its value even if APP goes offline. (see screen without internet)

code :

```
var coffeeCountRef = firebase.database().ref('/dailyConsumption' + '/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/'+  today );

        coffeeCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {

   //code to calculate the number

}
```

[Screen with internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xzM6.png)

And to fetch the task list I am using list observable as follow :

```
    this.todaystasks = af.database.list('/userProfile/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + '/tasks',{
    query:{
        orderByChild:'date',
        equalTo  : today
    }
}) as FirebaseListObservable<any>;
```

But when I want to see this task list in offline mode I could not retrieve the list. It seems the list values are not cached.

[Screen without internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ilvw.png)

I would like to see this screen loaded even if in offline mode.

I saw in firebase.js documentation that it supports offline capabilities whereas I do not find how to achieve the same with AngularFire 2.

Just to add I am using IONIC 2 RC 1.0 with
Firebase 3 and angularfire 2.

Comment: What do you mean by cached?

Comment: i wanted to see the listobservables output which are once loaded in network connection , to be present if I switch the network or network breaks for sometime..When a component is loaded with firebase.ref().on event it remains in the cache even if network breaks which is not the case with angularfire 2 observables. So If I want to achieve similar functionality how can I implement. - Thanks!!

Comment: Okay, can you include the specific sequence of events (e.g. subscribe, disconnect from network, etc.) and the expected behaviour in your question and include the ref usage, too? Internally, AF2 uses refs, so it's not clear what's different re: network disconnection.

Comment: @cartant updated my question.